# Observable subscribe not getting called on same value

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I have a BehaviourSubject as a callback for my Retrofit method.

```
private val loadCompleted = BehaviourSubject.create<List<String>>()
```

Inside my retrofit OnResponse/onFailure, I call

```
loadCompleted.onNext(myList) //inside retrofit onResponse and 
loadCompleted.onError("Error") // inside retrofit onFailure
```

I am subscribed to a function which returns loadCompleted.

```
fun loadingCompleted() : Observable<List<String>>{return loadCompleted}
```

and then I subscribe to the loadingCompleted as

```
loadingCompleted.subscribe{list -> 
     //only called once
     anotherfun(list)
}
```

The first time my Retrofit function gets called, I am able to get my subscribe called but subsequent calls to the same function doesn't fire the subscribe. I am assuming the calls normally return the same value because it is just a refresh and the data might not have changed. However, I still need to get the subscribe called so I can react accordingly. I have tried both BS and ReplaySubject but the result is the same. How do I use an observable to ensure I always get the subscribe called whenever I call onNext(x)/onComplete(x) even though x might not have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably finishing your `BehaviorSubject` stream with `onComplete`/`onError`. If you don't want to do that, wrap x/error to some kind of Result which is sealed class and has `Success` and `Failure` subclasses. Then always use `subject.onNext()` to emit.

```
sealed class Result<T> {
    class Success<T>(val t: T) : Result<T>()
    class Failure<T>(val e: Throwable) : Result<T>()
}

class Test {
    val subject: BehaviorSubject<Result<List<String>>> = BehaviorSubject.create()

    fun call() {
        subject.onNext(Result.Success(listOf("example")))
        subject.onNext(Result.Failure(RuntimeException("error")))

        subject.subscribe{result->
            when(result){
                is Result.Success -> print(result.t)
                is Result.Failure -> print(result.e.message)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Would you mind giving me an example of how I could do that? I am new to Rx programming and trying to wrap my head around it. Thanks